# Validate file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have validation:

```
public function saveUser($request)
    {
        // validacja
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'surname' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ]);

        if ($request->hasFile('userPicture')) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'userPicture' => 'image|max:1000'
            ]);
        }

        // save
    }
```

I need add to this validation:

```
'userPicture' => 'image|max:1000'
```

- file type: only jpg/jpeg

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
'userPicture' => 'max:1000|mime:image/jpeg'
```

The documentation states you can use the following mime types:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

*image/jpeg* allows for: *image/jpeg - jpeg jpg jpe*

For more information:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Laravel version there are some different ways.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-image
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Mime is a filetype rule that you need to set.

So, you can first make the rules array and then validate:

```
public function saveUser($request)
{
    // validacja
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'surname' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ];

    if ($request->hasFile('userPicture')) {
        $rules['userPicture'] = 'image|max:1000|mimes:jpeg'
    }

    $this->validate($request, $rules);
    // save
}
```